# ALAssetsLibrary causes "Store configuration failed. Creating new database." Message

Tags: ios5

EDIT: I am using a shared instance of the ALAssetsLibrary in the AppDelegateController, and have debugged it several times and see that the lifespan of the library seems to be for as long as the app is running.

```
static ALAssetsLibrary *library;

+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)sharedLibrary {

  if(library == nil) {
    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  }
  return library;
}
```

I am executing the following code in an iOS 5 (release) app:

```
[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init]
```

Frustratingly, I see the following:

`Store configuration failed. Creating new database. (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134010 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134010.)" UserInfo=0x329b30 {metadata=<CFBasicHash 0x34f3b0 [0x3e7a3630]>{type = immutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
, reason=The store type in the metadata does not match the specified store type.})`

This causes the UIImagePickerController to not see any of the phone's stored photos.

I am running this on an iPhone 4. I'm unsure if this matters, but this app was originally built for iOS 4.3, and recently we were upgrading a few things to iOS 5.0 compatibility.

Is anyone else running into this? Any work arounds or solutions exist?

I've been doing a lot of Googling and searching the Apple Forums, but haven't had any luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Photo Library is corrupt. Please perform the following steps:

1. Sync your device one time with iTunes
2. Open the Photos app on your device.

This should rebuild the Photo-Library.
Then try to run your app again.

Cheers,

Hendrik

Comment: I forgot to mention that we've tested this on about 5 other devices, so I don't think it is likely corrupt photo libraries here.